# Serve large file async and then delete it

Tags: async-await, asp.net-web-api2

Using Web API 2, I have a process that generates a temporary file for the purpose of writing it to the output stream for client consumption.  The process can be somewhat long running, taking a few minutes to complete.

What I'd like to do is serve the file asynchronously and then delete it upon completion or cancellation (connection timeout).

Would something like this be close?  I haven't tested yet, but I'm wondering of the continue will delete the file before it's served entirely.

```
public class FileCreationResult
{
    public String FilePathOut { get; set; }
}

public class MyFileCreationProcess{
    const string NaiveDefaultTempFilePath = @"c:\temp\mytempfile.bin";

    public FileCreationResult Execute(){
        // do stuff that makes a file

        File.WriteAllBytes(NaiveDefaultTempFilePath, NaiveDefaultTempFilePath);
        return new FileCreationResult{
            FilePathOut = NaiveDefaultTempFilePath
        };              
    }   
}

public class Controller : ApiController
{
    private readonly MyFileCreationProcess process;

    public Controller(MyFileCreationProcess process)
    {
        this.process = process;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponse> GetFile(CancellationToken cancellationToken){
        return await Task.Run(()=>{
            var fileCreationResult = process.Execute();         
            using( var stream = File.OpenRead(fileCreationResult.FilePathOut)){
                var response = Request.CreateResponse();                
                response.Content = new StreamContent( stream);
                return response;
                //
                // I would like to delete the file at path fileCreationResult.FilePathOut
                // after it has been written to the output stream..
                // how would I do this ?
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: do you just have a stream you want to write to disk? or do you want to wait until the file stream has been written?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  I expanded on my code sample a bit to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably just get away with a try finally block

```
public async Task<HttpResponse> GetFile(CancellationToken cancellationToken){
    return await Task.Run(()=>{
        var fileCreationResult = process.Execute();
        try{
        using( var stream = File.OpenRead(fileCreationResult.FilePathOut)){
            var response = Request.CreateResponse();                
            response.Content = new StreamContent( stream);
            return response;
        }
        }finally{
           if(File.Exists(fileCreationResult.FilePathOut))
           {
              File.Delete(fileCreationResult.FilePathOut);
           }
        }
    });
}
```

or if you want to use `continueWith`:

```
public Task<HttpResponse> GetFile(CancellationToken cancellationToken){
    string path;
    return  Task.Run(()=>{
        var fileCreationResult = process.Execute();
        path = fileCreationResult.FilePathOut;

        using( var stream = File.OpenRead(path)){
            var response = Request.CreateResponse();                
            response.Content = new StreamContent( stream);
            return response;
        }
        }).ContinueWith(x=>{
            if(File.Exists(fileCreationResult.FilePathOut))
           {
              File.Delete(fileCreationResult.FilePathOut);
           }
        });
}
```

I should note I don't have a C# compiler handy so it may not compile but I think you get the point.